# The issue is about mpandroidchart-linechart yAxis value

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use mpandroidchart for my project to show linechart,my yAxis value is puted Arraylist,for example {"0.9568","1.3294,"4.5238"},I use the method Float.parseFloat() to change the string type to float type.look at the following code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            String unitnetvalue = list1.get(i).getUnitnetvalue();
            float unitVal = Float.parseFloat(unitnetvalue);
            //float unitVal=Float.valueOf(unitnetvalue);
            //float unitVal=Float.parseFloat(unitnetvalue.replaceAll(",", ""));
            yVals.add(new Entry(unitVal, i));
            xVals.add(list1.get(i).getEnddate());
            zdVals.add(list1.get(i).getNetastrate());
            list.add(unitVal);
        }
```

then the yAxis will show the value is 1,1,4,I want show the value 0.9568,1.3294,4.5238,how can I do for what I want?

Comment: Please check this link: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface.

Comment: Thanks very much, this link is about yAxis valueFormatter:https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-YAxisValueFormatter-interface